# SugarCRM custom field smarty REQUEST_URI

Tags: php, smarty, sugarcrm

I'm trying to use smarty php for listview custom code.

Given the example url, http://www.example.com/sub-dir/index.php

and the custom field define in **vardef.php**

```
    'customCode' => '<a href="{$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]}/index.php?action=EditView&module=Tasks&record={$ID}&isDuplicate=true" target="_blank">Create</a>',
```

This will generate a custom hyperlink which should look like `http://www.example.com/sub-dir/index.php?action=EditView&module=Tasks&record=d20f361d-a26e-a1bb-ecb8-53db406a758c&isDuplicate=true`

However, `{$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]}` does not return any value.

How to include REQUEST_URI in customCode?

Comment: Have u tried var_dump($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]);

Answer (score -1):

Please use this code

```
'customCode' => "<a href='{$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]}/index.php?action=EditView&module=Tasks&record={$ID}&isDuplicate=true' target='_blank'>Create</a>",
```

instead of using this

```
'customCode' => '<a href="{$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]}/index.php?action=EditView&module=Tasks&record={$ID}&isDuplicate=true" target="_blank">Create</a>',
```

Comment: Hi GuyT, if you see my code is in between double quote. And this is working code you can also verify it before saying it wrong. :)

Comment: Hi Melvin, Have you tested the solution?

Comment: Finally it work like this 

`'customCode' => '<a href="' . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] . '/index.php?action=EditView&module=Tasks&record={$ID}&isDuplicate=true" target="_blank">Create</a>'`